# Transferring SQL 2008 DB

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an SQL 2008 DB and I need to transfer the structure and the data to an off site, off network database.  I need to somehow create a physical file that represents the structure and data within the db that can be loaded in another instance of SQL Server 2008.  What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight backup and restore should do the trick with [Force restore over existing database] option set on restore.

Comment: Alright thanks.  I haven't even looked into this, but it sounds like cake.  How big will the generated file be?  This is of course dependent on the data, but does it contain indexes and other internal stuff?  I don't really care one way or another, just curious.